# How to deny or invert the memory address

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I'm doing some tasks and I need to solve the following problem:
I need to load with a descending table, this table starts at the value 0000 and ends with ffff, for example:

```
Addres    value
0000      ffff
0001      fffe
0002      fffd
....      ....
....      ....
ffff      0000
```

My code:

```
mov ax,0000
mov bx,0000
not bx
mov ax,bx ; this is line 41
inc ax
dec bx
cmp ax,ffff
jne 41 
int 3
```

directly, this code does not work, does nothing. I don't have great knowledge in assembly and I can't detect the error.

Comment: Many many problems in your code. 1/ you never write anything to memory and cannot fill any array 2/ your algorithm is incorrect and does not do what you want (mov on line 41 breaks everything) 3/ 0x0 is a special address for processors. When trying to read or write at this address an exception is raised. This is the reason why dereferencing a null pointer raises a 'bus error'. So your table cannot be located a this address. 4/ you should use labels for branches and for in memory addresses (including your array). All assemblers have this kind of facilities.

Comment: @AlainMerigot: This is x86-16, presumably real mode.  These addresses might all be offsets from a non-zero DS segment base.  And besides that, real-mode x86-16 puts the IVT (interrupt vector table) at physical address 0 by default, so reading/writing linear address 0 is not an error on x86.  ([What does physical address 0 in x86 Linux contain?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/461689) mistakenly quotes some real-mode stuff)    x86 doesn't have bus errors, either, unless you enable alignment checking.  Then you can get a `#AC` exception.

Comment: I mean the addresses in the table.  The code is nonsense containing no memory accesses, as you say.  And BTW, given the context this might be a program for `debug.exe`, which doesn't support labels.  That would also explain the `ffff` with no leading 0 or suffix, because debug.exe treats all numbers as hex by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Successive addresses store a single byte that can hold values from 0 to 255**. For the values from 0 to FFFFh that you want to store, you would need 131072 bytes (65536*2). 
In 16-bit mode (real address mode) a memory segment can have 65536 bytes making your task a bit complicated!

```
    cld
    xor     di, di    ; Address 0000h
    mov     ax, FFFFh ; Value
More:
    stosw
    dec     ax
    js      More
```

This will store 32768 descending word-values at offset addresses 0, 2, 4, 6, ... , 65534.
At this point you would have to change the `ES` segment register by adding 2048 to it.
Then continu with next code:

```
    ; DI=0 AX=7FFFh 
More_:
    stosw
    dec     ax
    jnz      More_
```

A byte solution is possible however:

```
    mov     bx, 0
    mov     al, 255
Next:
    mov     [bx], al
    inc     bx
    dec     al
    jnz     Next

    ; 0000  FF
    ; 0001  FE
    ; 0002  FD
    ;
    ; 00FE  01
    ; 00FF  00
```

A byte solution using 1 register:

```
    xor     bx, bx
 ext:
    mov     [bx], bl
    not     byte ptr [bx]
    inc     bx
    test    bl, bl
    jnz     Next

    ; 0000  FF
    ; 0001  FE
    ; 0002  FD
    ;
    ; 00FE  01
    ; 00FF  00
```

Comment: The table would make sense if it was showing the value after sign-extension from byte to word.  But that would be really weird and confusing.